# I would like to know if someone has applescript to loop al my stickynotes and put it in a textfile

Tags: mac, applescript

I have been meaning to do this for a while, but I never got around to do it.
The problem is that I have to do research how applescript works.

Anyway, I have now collected over 200 snippets for my programming, but I need to sort them out
Putting them all in a textfile with some obvious breaks inbetween I could sort them and tag them for another snippet programm.

This is my first question here, so I hope I am at the right place, maybe stack overflow is also a good place to ask

Thanks in advannce, if someone already has done this or knows how to do this

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stickies isn't scriptable, but you can get the contents of notes if access for assistive devices is enabled.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Stickies"
    set notes to value of text area 1 of scroll area 1 of windows
end tell
set text item delimiters to linefeed
set the clipboard to notes as text
```

(Just run the code above in AppleScript Editor.)